# Is anyone having problems with the If function in Excel? It keeps automatically moving where I want to put my )'s

Tags: microsoft-excel, brackets, if

I am typing a similar formula to =if(a1="No","Not Applicable",'Data'!a3).  But when I get to the A3 Excel automatically moves my cursor to just after the e" and wants to enter whatever I type there.  As soon as I click on after the A3 it moves my cursor again.  I'm have the same problem when concatenating but using the & to join text and inputs.

Comment: (1) You say “I'm have the same problem when concatenating but using the `&` to join text and inputs.” I’m not 100% sure what you mean. Do you mean `CONCATENATE(A1,B1)` has the problem and `A1&B2` doesn’t? Or vice-versa? (2) Please do some experimentation.  Does the problem persist when you exit Excel and restart it? Reboot? (3) How many other functions have you tested? (4) What happens if you type the entire formula into some other program (e.g., Notepad) and then copy & paste it into Excel? … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have entered "No" in A1
Now in A2 I have entered the following formula :

=IF(A1="No", "Not Applicable" , 'Data'! B10)

So Because the word "No" is there in A1; TRUE, Therefore it displays in

A2 : " Not Applicable ", without inverted comas, you know.

Now in My Data Sheet, In B10 I have entered "Thank You."

So moment I change A1 = "Yes", say......

In A2, it displays ......  Thank You.

Thanks.